# Auth facade suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an install that worked consistently until for some reason after install Auth facade stopped working.
I did run `composer dump-autoload`, then `php artisan clear-compiled` .

But i'm still getting

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Auth::user() in somePath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 207`

I didn't change any code or the laravel version, so it must be something else.
I'm running laravel 5.0.16.

Anyone have an idea where to start looking?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try `\Auth::user()`?

It seems to be looking for the `user()` method in `Facade.php` which is not correct. That suggests to be that you have an incorrect or missing "use" statement in the PHP file you are calling this method from.

Comment: I don't think the usage is incorrect, same code working in other installs we have.
It has to be something that going wrong with new installation.